# Can you say "it's ten o'clock p.m."?

Tags: american-english, british-english, time-reference

This might be a question of individual style, but it still bothers me:

The words in the title are part of the lyrics of swiss singer Jael Malli in her song "Driving with You" on her album here (20 seconds into the song): https://www.jaelmusic.ch/music

I would think, as an American speaker, one would say

> ten p.m.

from a British speaker, I would expect to hear

> ten o'clock in the evening

Is the combination

> it's ten o'clock p.m.

actually used anywhere?

*Note: I am specifically asking about the o'clock part in combination with AM/PM, not about leaving out the o'clock part as in [Answering about the time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128803/answering-about-the-time)*

Comment: it's redundant, but don't expect any song to be perfectly grammatical (particularly, when the author isn't an English native)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Answering about the time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128803/answering-about-the-time)

Answer (score 1):

While most grammar references will rightfully consider using both redundant, the *o'clock a.m./p.m.* form is still used sometimes - particularly in spoken English, where you might start saying "ten o'clock" and then partway through realize it might not be clear enough for the listener, but also in cases like [the title of this exhibit in the Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/resource/rbpe.1440320a/?sp=2) or [this picnic announcement](https://www.ahboregon.org/annual-member-picnic-thursday-august-15-6-oclock-pm/).

Or, like in your example, in poetry and songs, where proper English is sometimes bent a bit to match the rhythm.